# Joomla File Permission for Users

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a couple of .pdf files on my webspace. Typically I just link them per Joomla Editor. The link ist only for already logged in users, so no guests can them see.

The problem is, that I can access the .pdf file per link directly without log-in. Thats a security problem, which shouldnt there. I want to set directory permissions for joomla user groups. I already tried ProFiles, but with no success. I picked my directory as root and set the permission i wanted. After I've set the file permissions via ftp to 600 and I have no access whether logged-in or not.

Already thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you don't use any [download manager](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/downloads) component?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to use [Attachment](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/attachments) component. It's a simple component that allows you to add / attach file to joomla article. It also allows you to restrict file access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is a hotlink protection on your pdf files.
You could use this tool to generate the code to be added to your .htaccess file: 
http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @webchun, it is probably easiest to use a [downloads extension](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/directory-a-documentation/downloads) although there are solutions to this issue if you are comfortable with coding something yourself.

For more details, see [prevent direct access to PDF link for guest users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22771822/1983389)